# FPS drop on rendering

Tags: java, rendering

I am trying to create my own game in java  (without OpenGL, LWJGL etc) and I am having a problem with the rendering.

My map is pretty big and the game redering the entire map at once which cause a result of 2 fps.

Does anyone know how I can make my game to render only what the player see and not the entire map?

map loading code:

```
private void loadMap(BufferedImage image) {
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    

    for(int i = 0; i<w; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<h; j++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(i, j);
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
            
            if(red >=250) 
                handler.addObject(new Wall(i*32, j*32, ID.Wall));
        
            if(green==255)
                handler.addObject(new Floor(i*32, j*32, ID.Floor));
        }
    }   
}
```

camera code:

```
public void tick(GameObject object) {
    
    x += ((object.getX()-x)-Game.WIDTH/2)*0.05f;
    y += ((object.getY()-y)-Game.WIDTH/2)*0.05f;
    
}

    g2d.translate(-camera.getX(), -camera.getY());
    handler.render(g);
    maps.render(g);
    g2d.translate(camera.getX(), camera.getY());
```

more codes for MCVE:

```
public synchronized void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
     long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0 ;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
}

public void tick(){
    for(int i = 0; i<handler.objects.size(); i++) {
        if(handler.objects.get(i).getId() ==ID.Player) {
            camera.tick(handler.objects.get(i));
            hud.tick();
        }
    }
}

public class Window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6357664197674207224L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }   
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    new Game();
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    //GameState
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    if(GameState == STATE.game) {
    g2d.translate(-camera.getX(), -camera.getY());
    handler.render(g);
    g2d.translate(camera.getX(), camera.getY());
    hud.render(g);
    }
```

Comment: What does your profiler say about this?

Comment: There are a few issues with this question. For instance: your title implies that you have a drop in FPS, how do you know it's the _rendering_ of your map? How do you render your map; if you have rolled your own rendering mechanism, you should probably tell us about it. Also, note that using OS calls instead of the graphics cards drivers to do rendering is known to be particularly slow.

Comment: I know the rendering of the map cause the issue because when I had small map I had 100fps ish and when I made her bigger it dropped to 2 fps. About the rendering mechanism I am just a begginer so I am basically just doing a game loop that calls the render method every time. Also how can I do graphics cards call instead?

Comment: _"small map I had 100fps ish and when I made her bigger it dropped to 2 fps"_ This _could_ be related to the rendering, but it could also be related to something else you do with your map, for instance, if you call `loadMap(BufferedImage image)` every frame, you could really be trashing your garbage collector because of the amount of `new` you're doing. This is why I suggest you take your profiler and see where the bottlneck is. _" Also how can I do graphics cards call instead?"_ Use OpenGL or libGDX, they wrap this for you.

Comment: To help us debug your code, please provide an [MCVE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it). We currently don't have enough information to tell you what to do to improve the rendering.

Comment: You wouldn't be following tutorials from RealTutsGML on YouTube would you? I kind of recognize the code you're writing. If you are I would suggest against it. Noting personal about him, that's how I first got into Java development too (look at my oldest questions :)) but he teaches some VERY bad practices and uses outdated libraries (such as raw Java). I understand you want to do this without 3rd party libraries but there is really no reason not to use a library such as LibGDX, it makes your life 100x easier and has really good documentation (google LibGDX wiki).

Comment: i did followed him and some others but i just want my first project to be without thrid party libraries for giving myself sort of a challenge

Comment: Added more code for MCVE

Comment: Can you post your `render()` function?

Comment: I added my render function

Comment: It looks like this calls `maps.render`, `handler.render`, and `hud.render` to do most of the actual rendering work, so you still haven't helped us identify the code that's slow.

Comment: Where is the code which actually renders the map?

Comment: The map render after the handler (probably was removed somehow when copied that?)

Comment: What more code u need to identify the slow?